# Pointcloud_to_laserscan based on recorded data

Tags: openni, rosbag, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I recorded some kinect data using openni with rosbag. Now i want to replay the data set and transform the 3D measurement into a laserscan. pointcloud_to_laserscan offers this function but it is embedded into a openni nodelet. If I started the corresponding launch file

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch
```

pointcloud_to_laserscan started, but no connection was established to rosbag. I allready checked the topic names ...

I assume it is not possible to execute the code out of the nodelet? Do you know another package that offers such a function?

Best wishes

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47853/pointcloud_to_laserscan-based-on-recorded-data/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just load the pointcloud_to_laserscan nodelet in a nodelet manager and leave out all other nodelets. Have a look [here](http://ros.org/wiki/nodelet) for more information on nodelets. To launch a single nodelet in a standalone node, you can use:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="point_cloud_to_laser_manager" output="screen" args="standalone pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
    <!-- heights are in the (optical?) frame of the kinect -->
    <param name="min_height" value="-0.025"/>
    <param name="max_height" value="0.025"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="/narrow_scan"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I just copied the relevant parts from kinect.launch and put them in a standalone nodelet. Note that the nodelet listens on /cloud_throttled, i.e. you either must record that topic, remap your point cloud topic to it in `rosbag play` or change the remapping in the above launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2012-11-09**:
Thanks a lot, it works now !!!